# Automatically Run SSIS Package From Where Stopped after Server Connection Timeout

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

Been working on a SSIS package for a few days now.  Server keeps timing out halfway through package execution.  I have a ForEach Loop container that is looping through a directory of excel files to import the excel data into SQL Server; there is about 500 files in the directory.  This is starting to become very time consuming because my server has been timing out.  My question is this:

Is there a script I could write to have this package run from where it left off as the server timed out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Checkpoints to make your package start from where it stopped in the last run. As always, [MSDN documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140226.aspx) is a good place to start.

Comment: MSDN states that checkpoints are not honored by For Loop and ForEach loop containers